Back up sqlite to io.Writer?
I have a SQLite database which I'm accessing via mattn/go-sqlite3. I want to perform a live snapshot of that database. The catch is that the backup must be saved to an io.Writer instance. Specifically, I am implementing the SaveSnapshot() function for a raft implementaiton.
I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use SQLite's online backup system to pipe to this Writer instance. Is there a special file or named pipe I can use as the output database?
More generally, I want to do an online snapshot and backup of my sqlite database. While SQLite has a backup system out of the box, I don't see how I can use it for a writer. I would be fine running a SELECT statement and copying data to my writer, but I am again not sure how to ensure I am seeing just a current snapshot of the data while allowing updates to happen while this is taking place.

Would backing up to a temporary file and then shoveling its content to that io.Writer work for you? I'm asking because "the backup" functionality is likely to require a random-access destination file. It's possible to dump an SQLite database (grab its source code and see how the .dump shell command is implemented—basically, it's 3 SQL queries) to a stream, but it would dump SQL statements, not "native" backup format.

Ideally, I would avoid the temporary file. The purpose of this snapshot is to duplicate data to a new machine, which could be streamed. However, for that to work, it assumes that the backup process does not require random writes. I don't know if that is the case for sqlite's online backups.

A cursory look at the backup code hints it indeed requires random access to the destination file. So, I guess my initial assessment appears to hold true: you either go with the temporary file which you shovel at your destination once the backup is complete or go with SQL dump, wihch is streamable, and recreate the destination DB from that dump on the receiving end (whatever it is).
